# Visual studio code,HTML attributes quotes auto close

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using Visual studio Code now. However one feature I miss which can be kind of annoying is the automatic closing of the double quotes. For instance when I write:
`<div class=">` most text editors would automatically put a second double quote there (Like this: `<div class="">`)

### Question:

Is there a package or a setting which can make visual studio code auto complete the double quotes of my attributes?

Comment: It does automatically put the second quote in for me unless in the middle of another tag like: <div class="someClass><span="</div>  then when typing that inner span tag it won't put the second quote in.  Seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VS Code will auto close the double quotes in an html tag so long as you are not typing with the cursor next to the right angle bracket (the `>` character).

So if you start typing `<p class="` then Code will expand that to `<p class=""`.

However, if you first type `<p>` then move the cursor back between the `p` and `>` characters and start typing `<p class=">` then the second double quote will not get inserted.

[From this discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/18071), it appears quote auto-inserting works when the next character is either a newline or whitespace.  The reasoning behind the behavior is that the quote auto-inserting is supposed to be active when typing new code, but inactive when modifying code.

The takeaway is this: if you want quote auto insertion to work the way you want, keep that cursor out in front of the line.

It looks like changing this behavior [had an issue opened](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/42956), but it is not implemented yet.

Bonus: [based on this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26820#issuecomment-325959447) I made a keybinding that will make the double quotes auto insert a second quote and place the cursor focus in the middle of the two quotes, which is probably what you're expecting.  To use this, copy & paste this into Code's keybindings.json.  Here's one way to edit keybindings.json: In VS Code, press `CTRL-K` then `CTRL-S`, then towards the top click "keybindings.json" where it says "For advanced customizations open and edit keybindings.json".

The keybinding:

```
{
    "key": "shift+'",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {"snippet": "\"$1\""}
}
```

Example keybindings.json using the keybinding above:

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to overwrite the defaults
[
    {
        "key": "shift+'",
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "when": "editorTextFocus",
        "args": {"snippet": "\"$1\""}
    }
]
```